# Timeout in API between two pages of a website in amazon ec2 server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, server

I have my application hosted in amazon ec2 webserver.
I am using a NGINX server in a Ubuntu 14.04.5.

In certain moment one page of my application make a request to my JSON API.
In this moment the page sometimes load and sometimes doesn't. I receive this message in my error logs (with some arrangement ):

```
2016/10/12 15:24:48 [error] 5504#5504: *162316 FastCGI sent in stderr: 

"PHP message: PHP Warning:

fopen(https://my.site.com/link/to/other/page):

failed to open stream:

Connection timed out in /srv/www/path/to/a/file.php on line 64" while reading response header from upstream,

client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx,

server: my.server.name.com,

request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 

upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000",

host: "my.server.name.com"
```

This started when we restarted the server in amazon, then we had to updated the elastic IP number in our OVH for our domain name.

The page he tries to access (https://my.site.com/link/to/other/page) is working normally when we access it directly.

OBS.: Normally it is not the keep alive time, because the page respond very fast

There is any way of debugging this problem? The weirdest is that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.